# Google Maps API v2 not loading... worked fine yesterday

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2, android-maps-v2, mapfragment

I know this has been an asked and reasked question but however i get this strange behaviour. No crashes but the map is not loading anymore.

I am trying to use Google Maps for my Android application. I managed to load my map yesterday but today when i tried running the app i get the following error:

```
08-01 10:40:50.374: I/Google Maps Android API(5605): Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.
08-01 10:41:05.649: E/Google Maps Android API(5605): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).
```

This is my Activty where i try to open the map:

```
public class LocationActivity extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap map;
    private RelativeLayout cancel_btn;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        getActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.preview_location);
        cancel_btn = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);

        cancel_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onBackPressed();
            }
        });

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();

        if (map != null) {
            retrieveLocation();
        } else {

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        map.clear();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    private void retrieveLocation() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String staddress = intent.getStringExtra("location");
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.US);

        try {
            List<Address> loc = geocoder.getFromLocationName(staddress, 5);
            double latitude = loc.get(0).getLatitude();
            double longitude = loc.get(0).getLongitude();

            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                    new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title(staddress));

            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(latitude, longitude), 12));

            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12), 2000, null);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("IOException", e.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(this, "IOException:  " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }

}
```

And the XML:

```
<fragment
        android:layout_weight="6"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Manifest XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.captoom"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.back"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />

    <permission
        android:name="ro.gebs.captoom.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:name="ro.gebs.captoom.utils.CaptoomApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="AA_DB_NAME"
            android:value="captoom.db" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="AA_DB_VERSION"
            android:value="1" />

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <activity
            android:name="ro.gebs.captoom.activities.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="ro.gebs.captoom.activities.TakePicture" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="ro.gebs.captoom.activities.PreviewPhoto" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="ro.gebs.captoom.activities.AddReceiptActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="ro.gebs.captoom.activities.EditReceiptActivity" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="ro.gebs.captoom.activities.LocationActivity" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAzIsgylRUb3yxrh-9BsgBJcVo0M4UOhyU" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I updated my API Key today still no result... any ideas?

Comment: did you change in menifest something like change the package name?

Comment: are you sure that you are not using a wrong keystore or package name? and remember changing the same key in manifest too.

Comment: post the manifest code here

Comment: no changes to the manifest with regards to the package name, just the API KEY metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

brother do you give all the permission and changed the package name according to your Google Api key. Now you have to paste your manifest file code.